# Как узнать на какой объект относится тот или иной адрес в памяти?

Tags: c#

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process theprocess in processlist) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

данный код показывает все процессы в системе..
Вопрос такой: как можно узнать через код, на какой объект относится тот или иной адрес, то есть вот запустил я гугл хром, хочу знать какой адрес в памяти отвечает за адресную строку?

P.S. на экране должно выводится что-то типа

Сам процесс, его ИД, (то что уже имею) + адрес памяти и за что этот адрес отвечает..в этом процессе..

Comment: И что вы потом будете делать с этим адресом? | Используйте утилиту Spy++ (встроена в Visual Studio), чтобы находить _окна_ приложений. Потом можно слать сообщения этим окнам.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить ответу вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086705/how-to-find-the-starting-address-of-an-application-for-memory-editing-a-process), то вот так можно получить адресс процесса

```
IntPtr startOffset = proc.MainModule.BaseAddress;
```